# I accidently messed my python plot up and cannot fix it now, however it worked 30 mins ago

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, python-requests

I did get it right, but  today I messed it up and no plotting can be done - get error message saying no numerical data to plot when literally 30 mins ago it was plotting - what did I do wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests

wikiurl='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviation_accidents_and_incidents#Statistics'

table_class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"
response=requests.get(wikiurl)
print(response.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
indiatable=soup.find('table',{'class':"wikitable"})

df=pd.read_html(str(indiatable))
# convert list to dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame(df[0])
print(df.head)



df = df.sort_values(['Year'], ascending=[1])



ax = df.plot(x='Year', y = 'Deaths[57]', title = 'Aviation Accidents and Incidents', figsize=(20,20), 
grid=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have some odd characters in your dataframe such as `?` which forces the column to be of `dtype = object` therefore, generating the error that it doesn't have numeric values to plot.
You can workaround this by previously converting all columns to numeric and turning the characters into `NaN` with `pd.to_numeric()` letting you have numeric columns, hence capable of generating a plot. This would be my workaround:

```
df = df.sort_values(['Year'], ascending=[1])
for i in df:
  df[i] = pd.to_numeric(df[i],errors='coerce')

ax = df.plot(x='Year', y = 'Deaths[57]', title = 'Aviation Accidents and Incidents', figsize=(20,20), 
grid=True)
```

And the plot looks like this, with the gaps accounting for the missing data. This missing data can be filled with various different methods such as `fillna()` and/or `interpolate()`:

[image]

Comment: With pleasure, feel free to accept my answer if it helped you solve the problem (:

Comment: Apologies but can anyone give me the code to fill the missing data. Especially 2001 data which was 9/11

Comment: hi @Raxephion!  Friendly reminder that people will be more inclined to help if you mark their answers as useful or correct

Comment: Id gladly do it, but how - Im new to this as Ive been helped out excellently?